# How can I curve fit this particular data plot using python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have to make a cdm diagram using the data from a fits file. I have successfully did so. Now the next task is to make a line which goes through the most populated area. so how can I do it?

I am not sure how to even start as I am weak at programming myself

```
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

leo = fits.open('Leo IV.fits')
data = leo[1].data

plt.scatter(data['M606']-data['M814'], data['M814'], color='k', s=1)
plt.title('Leo IV')
plt.gca().set_xlim([0.0,-0.8])
plt.gca().set_ylim([18,28])
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

This is what I get:
[image: Graph I got]

This is what I want:

[image]

How can I make the green line appear in my graph?

Comment: with a spline or a polynomial fit

Comment: to my knowledge, `matplotlib` alone cannot do that. `seaborn` can automatically plot linear trends or splines using `seaborn.lmplot` or `seaborn.regplot`. These can't produce duplicate values on the x-axis though, only "regular" functions. I guess what you want is to fit a spline / lowess with `numpy`, `scipy` or `sklearn` and then plot that model with `matplotlib`.

Comment: As an experienced Python programmer myself: You may want to have a go practicing using the packages `numpy` (array and data manipulation), `scipy` (scientific computing tools like interpolation) and `matplotlib` (data plotting). Just mess around with them and see how they work. From experience, I can say that 95% of all basic problems can be solved using a combination of these three packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Here's a same code snippet:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    x = np.arange(0.0,10.0,0.1)
    y = 2*x**3 + 2

    fit = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit)

    plt.scatter(x, y)          # blue
    plt.scatter(x, fit_fn(x))  # orange
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

You shall this as your output:
[image: polyfit_plot]

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `Matlab`or `numpy` for polynomial curve fitting. Even a simple google sheet will also plot a `trendline` in the chart.

For `numpy`, check the function `polyfit` and `poly1d` for curve fit.

Comment: I did not get you.Can you show me a sample code please?